# Python ModuleNotFoundError when importing custom module

Tags: python

I'm working on an object detection project in Python and encountering a `ModuleNotFoundError` issue when attempting to import custom modules `Detections` and `BoxAnnotator` from `'supervision.tools.detections'`. The error message I'm facing is as follows:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yahyahajali/Python/ComputerVision-master/yolov8.py", line 8, in <module>
    from supervision.tools.detections import Detections, BoxAnnotator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'supervision.tools'
```

I'm working on an object detection script using Python, Torch, and OpenCV.
The Detections and BoxAnnotator classes are supposed to be imported from a custom module named `supervision.tools.detections`.
However, despite having these modules, I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError.

This is snip of code

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import cv2
from time import time
from ultralytics import YOLO

from supervision.draw.color import ColorPalette
from supervision.tools.detections import Detections, BoxAnnotator
```

Comment: Python cannot find a module named supervision.tools in your Python environment. Check Module Existence and Directory Structure.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I have installed supervision, by using this command pip install supervision

Comment: output of : from supervision import Detections, BoxAnnotator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
from supervision import Detections, BoxAnnotator
```

from official repo :

```
>>> from ultralytics import YOLO
>>> from supervision import Detections

>>> model = YOLO('yolov8s.pt')
>>> yolov8_results = model(IMAGE)[0]
>>> detections = Detections.from_yolov8(yolov8_results)
```

ensure install before import
https://github.com/roboflow/supervision